# Facebook "Mention Tagging" with Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, xamarin.ios, xamarin, tagging

I'm fairly new to FB Development and I'm trying to find out if anyone has managed to do Facebook "Mention Tagging" with Xamarin, similar to how it's done with the Foursquare app? It must be possible, unless Foursquare have a special arrangement with FB. ;-)

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/tagging/ https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/08/21/bringing-mention-tagging-to-open-graph/

Ideally I want to do a prototype with iOS, possibly going to Android one day but iOS is priority at the moment.  My goal is for the iOS App to be able to mention or tag a friend so they will see the post in their timeline.  I know FB have changed the rules slightly since Feb this year but I believe the two links above are still valid and Foursquare seem to be able to do it in their App.

Any help would be appreciated, even if it's just to say that it's not possible.  I've posed this question on a few forums now, like the Facebook and Xamarin ones but I'm not getting any feedback.  I've played around with the Xamarin Facebook SDK components but as yet no joy.

Thanks in advance.

Stephen

Comment: Its certainly possible, but you need to provide your code snippet which you use to post the status. Without being aware about the SDK or your method of posting, I doubt anybody can help you. In simple terms, you need to add a tags parameter to your status call with the id of the user you need to tag. For a more clear understanding, check your first link where they explain it quite simply/clearly and in detail.

Comment: Thanks Mohib, I simply just want to know if anyone has managed to do it using Xamarin (www.xamarin.com) and C#. I'm pretty new to FB development but I've played with both FB components on http://components.xamarin.com/ but with no luck.  If I can find out if someone has actually done it (other than Foursquare) then I'll spend more time trying to figure out a solution, which I'll then post for the community.

Comment: All I can say is.. Its absolutely possible. Its only a matter of adding a tags parameter to the API call. But FB also requires your app to be approved for Tagging.

Comment: Thanks Mohib, yes I've seen that, it should be OK during development / testing.  When I find out more I'll post it here.  Thanks.